# Rails - Handling custom attributes in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a shopping cart with multiple items that I display at checkout giving users the ability to delete items if required. The page also has a count of the total items in the cart that I am trying to update after an item is deleted. I get a 500 server response with this code.

How do I correctly return the remaining items and update it back on the HTML page?

```
  ##app/controllers/items_controller.rb

  def destroy
    @item = current_user.cart.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
    if @item.destroyed?
      render :status => 200, :json => {:success => true,:remaining => "#{pluralize(current_user.cart.count, 'item')}" }
    end    
  end
```

and my javascript file -

```
##app/assets/javascripts/cart.js.coffee

jQuery ($) ->
  $(".delete-link").bind "ajax:success", ->
    $("#cart-count").html(data.remaining)
    $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut()
    return
```

Comment: Do you have any logs on the error? If you go to `/log/production.log`, it will come back with any errors which caused the 500 exception

Comment: Thanks! I had to qualify the pluralize method with the complete class name. That fixed it. render :status => 200, :json => {:success => true,:remaining => "#{ActionController::Base.helpers.pluralize(current_user.cart.count, 'item')}" }